# Throttle a stream such that writes will be queued until a response was received to the previous write

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a stream which only allows one request/response at a time but is used in several threads.

Requests/commands should be throttled such that a new request can only occur once 
the previous request has been sent and a reply has been received.

The user would be able to do this

```
let! res = getResponse("longResp")
let! res2 = getResponse("shortResp")
```

and not really know or care about the throttle.

I have tried with a modified version of Tomas Petricek's [Throttling Agent](http://www.fssnip.net/oz) that allows async with return values, but this requires the user to call `getResponse("..") |> Enqueue |> w.Post` which is a recipe for disaster (in case they forget to do so).

Is there a good/idiomatic way of doing this in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then make it explicit in your type system that the returned type needs to be unwrapped with another function. So instead of returning an Async<'T> which as you pointed out can be called directly with Async.Start, rather return something like:

```
type Queuable<'T> = Queuable of Async<'T>
```

Then getResponse changes to return a Queueable:

```
let getResponse (s:string) =
  let r =
    async{
    do! write to your stream
    return! read from your stream
  }
Queuable r
```

Provide a function that unwraps the Queuable:

```
let enqueue (Queuable q) = async{
  return! processor.PostAndAsyncReply(fun replyChannel -> replyChannel,q)
}
```

The processor is an agent that simply runs the Async workflow. Something like this:

```
let processor = new MailboxProcessor<_>(fun inbox ->
  let rec Loop() = async {
    let! (r:AsyncReplyChannel<_>,job) = inbox.Receive()
    let! res = job
    r.Reply res
    return! Loop()}
  Loop())
```